# Partial sum of geometric distribution

Tags: probability

I am stuck with the following exercise, from *Probability* by Grimmett and Welsh.

> If $X$ is a discrete random variable having the geometric distribution
>   with parameter $p$, show that the probability that $X$ is greater that
>   $k$ is $(1-p)^k$.

My idea:
the required probability should be given by:
$$
P=\sum_{i=k}^\infty p(1-p)^i
$$
but how to sum this series? The only thing that came to my mind is:
$$
P = p\sum_{i=k}^\infty (1-p)^i = p \left(\frac{1}{p}-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(1-p)^i\right).
$$
But still I do not know how to sum the right hand side series.

Comment: Well...the geometric distribution attached to $p$ generally refers to an underlying binomial distribution with success probability $p$.  For $X$ to be greater than $k$ we need the first $k$ binomial trials to be fails so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1-p<1$ then as you wrote

> $$
> p \sum_{i=k}^{+\infty}\left(1-p\right)^{i}=p\frac{\left(1-p\right)^k}{1-\left(1-p\right)}=p\frac{\left(1-p\right)^{k}}{p}=\left(1-p\right)^{k}
> $$

Reminder : If $\left|x\right|<1$

$$
\sum_{n=p}^{+\infty}x^n=\frac{x^p}{1-x}
$$
It comes from 
$$
\sum_{n=p}^{N}x^n=\frac{1-x^{N-p+1}}{1-x}x^p \ \text{ (Partial  Sum of geometric sequences )}
$$
And
$$
x^{N-p+1} \underset{ N \rightarrow+\infty}{\rightarrow}0 \text{ because } \left|x\right|<1
$$
Hence the result.

Comment: Ok, but how do you prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}q=q^k$?

Comment: What you wrote is not good summing a constant $q$, $k$ times equals to $qk$.

Comment: You are right, I meant: $\sum_{i=k}^\infty q^i= \frac{1}{1-q}-\sum_{i=0}^\infty q^i=q^k$.

Comment: It's not true either it equals to what I wrote on the answer, do you want more detail ?

Comment: No, I think the answer by @alex-pavellas is clear on this, I wanted to write: $\sum_{i=k}^\infty q^i= \frac{1}{1-q}-\sum_{i=0}^\infty q^i=\frac{q^k}{1-q}$.

Answer (score 1):

A trick for summing geometric series when the index does not begin at 0:
Factor out the first term.

$\Sigma_{i=k}^{\infty} r^i=r^k+r^{k+1}+r^{k+2}+...$

Factoring out the $r^k$ turns this into:

$\Sigma_{i=k}^{\infty}r^i=r^k\left(1+r+r^2+...\right)$

The sum in the parentheses is your standard geometric series, which sums to $\frac{1}{1-r}$.

The value of the sum is thus:
$\Sigma_{i=k}^{\infty}r^i=\frac{r^k}{1-r}$

All of this of course assumes that $-1<r<1$, which is definitely true in your case, since $r=1-p$